# Comparison effective performance query topN between segmentGranularity by day and by hour

Tags: java, druid

I asked my question on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-user/SYWcqcr504k
But no one help me to get around this.

I am processing on large dataset. With the topN query on 2 case (segmentGranularity by day  vs segmentGranularity by hour) on the sam "queryGranularity"  is by "hour".

Case 01: by day

```
"granularitySpec" : {
        "type" : "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity" : "day",
        "queryGranularity" : "hour",
        "intervals" : ["2016-08-22/2016-08-23"]
      }
```

Case 02: by hour

```
"granularitySpec" : {
        "type" : "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity" : "hour",
        "queryGranularity" : "hour",
        "intervals" : ["2016-08-22/2016-08-23"]
      }
```

But the time of query on "segmentGranularity" : "day" is slower than "segmentGranularity" : "hour". Can anyone explain me about this case? Why segment by day is slower than by hour ? And between store data segment by day and by hour,  how can I choose the segment type? And how can it effect my query ?
Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider these things to decide the segment granularity:

- In case of realtime ingestion,segment granularity will dictate the time for which the realtime indexing tasks run.The coarser the segment granularity the longer these realtime indexing tasks will run.Realtime tasks will persist the data on the deep storage only when they complete hence if all the replicas of realtime tasks for a time interval gets killed,you will loose the data for that time interval.Hence segment granularity affects the risk of loosing the data.
  Finer segment granularity will mean more resources on the middle managers as multiple short task would be executing in parallel.
- Segment granularity also affects the size of the segments being created.
  In a basic setup, one segment file is created for each time interval, where the time interval is configurable by the segmentGranularity.
  In general,it is recommended to keep the segment size of the order of 300-700 MB and upto 5 millions rows.Hence this recommendation can also be used to decide the segment granularity.If very few and large segments are being produced,it will impact the parallelism of the query as the unit of parallelism is a segment.Hence large segments can sometimes slow down the query which could be the case when you created segments at day level.

I would also suggest you to look at various druid metrics emitted by the query nodes(i.e historical and realtime) to find out the bottleneck in case of slower query.
For various metrics please refer http://druid.io/docs/latest/operations/metrics.html

Comment: I have the sam answer on User Druid Google Group.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-user/SYWcqcr504k
Thanks so much